# How can I propagate the large binary output of one shell command as an argument to the next?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

On macOS, I would like to pipe the output of one command and pass it as an argument to another. The trouble is that the passed data are binary and if I use xargs it splits the bytestream with the following error:

```
xargs: unterminated quote
```

The reason for using xargs is to chunk the very large bytestream and hence avoid:

```
Argument list too long
```

xargs is not the right tool for the job though (see comments below).

How can I therefore achieve something *like* the following?

```sh
./v.sh | xargs command --argument $0
```

I have tried changing ulimit etc.

The use case is committing of a binary file as a Kubernetes secret.

Thanks!

Comment: If the command you wish to pass the binary data to is `grep`, there's no obvious reason why you would want to pass it as arguments, you should instead pass it through stdin (`./v.sh | grep pattern`)

Comment: It's not grep - it's an arbitrary command

Comment: Alright, and you're sure there's no way to pass it through something else than arguments? because `xargs` probably won't solve your problem, the way it avoids the "argument list too long" error is by splitting the argument list and invoking the command multiple times, which doesn't seem to be something that would work for you

Comment: Ahh thanks that's super useful to know. I was trying to avoid splitting in fact of course. Put another way: How do I pipe the large binary data from STDIN as an argument to the next command. If not `xargs`, then..?

Comment: to avoid splitting use quotes (which will avoid reaching the max number of arguments, but I think there's still a limit on overall size), but you really shouldn't use arguments to pass binary data

Comment: AFAIK `kubectl create secret generic test --from-literal` gives me no option...

Comment: Does `somecommand $(./v.sh)` not work?

Comment: @ghoti `-bash: /usr/local/bin/kubectl: Argument list too long`

Comment: @jtlz2 Looks like you could use `--from-file` instead of `--from-literal`, either using a real file which you would populate with the output of `./v.sh` or maybe using `-` which in many software represents stdin, and in this case piping the output of `./v.sh` into `kubectl`

Comment: Have a look at `xargs --show-limits < /dev/null`. Very much related to this question: [linux-command-line-character-limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/) and [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642) and

Comment: Well, [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/) might be a useful read. If you can't change ARG_MAX on your system, what about adapting your tools so that they can take data from stdin rather than args?

Comment: @Aaron `error: error reading -: no such file or directory` :(

Comment: @ghoti `somecommand $(./v.sh)` gives `Argument list too long` :(

Comment: Try with a real file then, as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-using-kubectl-create-secret) : `./v.sh > /tmp/testSecret ; kubectl create secret generic test --from-file=/tmp/testSecret; rm /tmp/testSecret` (looks like you might need two files though, but I'm not familiar with kubernetes)

Comment: @kvantour Thanks - agreed - but I couldn't get the ulimit fix to work on macOS. I would take it for sure. Also on macOS: `xargs` doesn't have `--show-limits`

Comment: @Aaron Might have to... Because these are in principle "secret" though I would rather avoid a tmpfile.

Comment: ghoti missed the quotes in his suggestion btw, you could try `kubectl create secret generic test --from-literal="$(./v.sh)"` (quoted argument -> no splitting over characters of IFS). Otherwise it looks like it would be possible to set the secret manually in which case you would encode the binary data in base64, which would take care of the spaces. The doc only suggest using the `apply` command which uses a file, but since there's a getter and many ways to manipulate the conf I wouldn't be surprised if you could use arguments or stdin

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your time. I put the quotes in and same problem. Perhaps a tmpfile is unavoidable.

Comment: To avoid a temp file, use process substitution syntax: `kubectl create secret generic test --from-file=<(./v.sh)`

Comment: @Poshi Works! Please could you add this as an answer and I will accept?? Thanks everyone for your input especially Aaron and ghoti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aaron suggested, you should avoid passing long arguments on the command line and rely on reading them from a file, so start using `--from-file` parameter.

To compute the command on the fly and give it to your command, you can use a process substitution:

```
kubectl create secret generic test --from-file=<(./v.sh)
```

The `<()...` syntax gets substituted by a file descriptor that the `kubectl` process can open and will have the contents of `./v.sh` computed on the fly. It is like a named pipe (which could be another solution to your problem).